# How to avoid accidentally sending sensitive fields from my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a new field on my model however this field contain sensitive information that should be as available as the models other fields.

Should I create a different model for my sensitive fields or should I keep them in the model ?
What is the practice to "mark" some fields as sensitive and make sure they dont get leaked by mistake by a generous json in an api call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the attributes to another model is one solution.

Another would be to override the [Serialization](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html) of your model. [Check how Devise implements it](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/354df3bc65fb211f0704208f52bf2213758585cf/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L106) to not return sensitive attributes (such as the `encrypted_password` and others they defined in [`BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/354df3bc65fb211f0704208f52bf2213758585cf/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb#L59))